# issue formatting file bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file(out.txt) like this:

```
fileOne.txt 100 ascii
fileTwo.txt 200 ascii
test        90  other
```

I want to create another file like this:

```
Filename    Size  Type
fileOne.txt 100   ascii
fileTwo.txt 200   ascii
test        90    other
```

and for this reason I used gawk command and my awk file is this:

```
BEGIN {
         print "-----------------------------------------------------\n"
         print "   Report files in directory\n\n"
         printf "\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n","File Name","Size","Type"
}
   {  
     printf "\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\n",$1,$2,$3

}
```

it works for me , but my problem is this:
if there is a file with long name,it's name goes also to the type column and the size value is printed all right under the size column, and I get a thing:

```
Filename    Type  Size
fileWithLongName.txt ascii   100
fileTwo.txt ascii 200
test        other    90
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a temporary file:

```
YOUR_AWK_SCRIPT_ABOVE | column -t > temp && mv temp ORIGINAL_FILENAME
```

`column -t` by default is delimit column by whitespaces. To specify a set of characters to delimit columns, you `-s` option.

You can use:

```
#name:script.awk
BEGIN{
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","File Name","Size","Type"
}
{
    printf "%s\t%s\t%d\n",$1,$2,$3
}
```

Then:

```
awk -f script.awk INPUT_FILENAME | column -s $'\t' -t > temp && mv temp INPUT_FILENAME
```

You can add:

```
print "-----------------------------------------------------\n"
print "   Report files in directory\n\n"
```

lines later after completing above command.

Comment: I think a temporary file is not necessary.

Comment: @Will i was unable to find how to write `column` output to file so I used the temporary file.